# Comparing means of two variables with the svy prefix in Stata (no ttest)

Tags: statistics, stata, survey, t-test

I am working with survey data and need to compare the means of a couple of variables. Since this is survey data, I need to apply survey weights, requiring the use of the svy prefix. This means that I cannot rely on Stata's `ttest` command. I essentially need to recreate the results of the following two `ttest` commands:

```
ttest bcg_vaccinated == chc_bcg_vaccinated_2, unpaired
ttest bcg_vaccinated == chc_bcg_vaccinated_2
```

`bcg_vaccinated` is a self-reported variable on BCG vaccination status while `chc_bcg_vaccinated_2` is BCG vaccination status verified against a child health card. You will notice that `chc_bcg_vaccinated_2` has missing values. These indicate that the child did not have a health card. So missing indicates no health card, 0 means the vaccination was not given, and finally, 1 means the vaccination was given. But this means that the variables have a different number of non-missing observations.

I have found the solution to the second `ttest` command, by creating a variable which is a difference between the two vaccination variables:

```
gen test_diff = bcg_vaccinated - chc_bcg_vaccinated_2 
regress test_diff
```

The above code runs only for the observations where both vaccination variables are non-missing, replicating the paired t-test listed above. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do the first version. The first version would compare the means of both variables on the full set of observations.

Here are some example data for the two variables. Each row represents a different child.

```
clear
input byte bcg_vaccinated float chc_bcg_vaccinated_2
0 .
1 0
1 1
1 1
1 0
0 .
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 0
0 .
1 1
1 1
0 .
1 1
1 1
1 0
0 .
1 0
1 0
1 0
0 .
0 .
1 1
0 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data into a suitable form for a regression:

```
. ttest bcg_vaccinated == chc_bcg_vaccinated_2, unpaired

Two-sample t test with equal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
bcg_va~d |      25         .68     .095219    .4760952    .4834775    .8765225
chc_bc~2 |      17    .5882353    .1230382    .5072997    .3274059    .8490647
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
Combined |      42    .6428571    .0748318    .4849656    .4917312    .7939831
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |            .0917647    .1536653               -.2188044    .4023338
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(bcg_vaccinated) - mean(chc_bcg_vaccin~2)          t =   0.5972
H0: diff = 0                                     Degrees of freedom =       40

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.7231         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.5538          Pr(T > t) = 0.2769

. display r(p)
.5537576

. quietly stack bcg_vaccinated chc_bcg_vaccinated_2, into(vax_status) clear

. quietly recode _stack (1 = 1 "SR") (2 = 0 "CHC"), gen(group) label(group)

. regress vax_status i.group

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        42
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 40)        =      0.36
       Model |  .085210084         1  .085210084   Prob > F        =    0.5538
    Residual |  9.55764706        40  .238941176   R-squared       =    0.0088
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0159
       Total |  9.64285714        41  .235191638   Root MSE        =    .48882

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  vax_status | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
         SR  |   .0917647   .1536653     0.60   0.554    -.2188044    .4023338
       _cons |   .5882353   .1185553     4.96   0.000     .3486261    .8278445
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. testparm 1.group

 ( 1)  1.group = 0

       F(  1,    40) =    0.36
            Prob > F =    0.5538

. display r(p)
.5537576
```

The `testparm` and `display` are not needed; they just show more digits.